# gridLayout of JButtons, actionListener for each JButton

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener, grid-layout

I have a gridLayout of JButtons. I'd like to distinguish every JButton from each other in the actionPerformed function. 
I don't want to "name" each JButton. The user press a JButton randomly. Is there any method to know which button has been pressed?
It is possible?

```
    [....]
    tUsuariCPU = new JButton[mida][mida];
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<size;j++){
            JButton temp = new JButton();
            tUsuariCPU[i][j] = temp; 
            temp.addActionListener(this);
            panel.add(temp);
        }
      }
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}
          [....]

   }
```

Comment: You can either use JButton.setName() to distinguish them (preferred) or you could create an ActionListener per button

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use a single `ActionListener`, you can check which Component fired the event by using the `getSource` button and comparing the instance to the JButton instances. Below uses a loop to loop over the 2D array of JButtons:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}
    for ( int i = 0; i < tUsuariCPU.length; i++ ){
        for ( int j = 0; j < tUsuariCPU[i].length; j++ ){
            if ( e.getSource() == tUsuariCPU[i][j] ){
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can add a single ActionListener per button, or set the ActionCommand of the JButton and use this value to determine which JButton fired the event (`e.getActionCommand().equals(myButton.getActionCommand())`)